# Is there a text to space table conversion for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a log file for whom I have defined a grok rule that maps some of the fields to an elasticsearch index with a series of fields of various types.

I want to make a projection: given 1TB of logfiles per month how much space I will have on elastiseach?
Is there some conversion table?